# Registering and using forms with Windsor

Tags: c#, winforms, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm trying to figure out how to use NHibernate/Windsor in a windows forms application. I have this in my main method:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var container = new WindsorContainer();

    var containerAdapter = new WindsorContainerAdapter(container);
    var MarketingDatabaseSessionFactory = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "config.config")).BuildSessionFactory();

    NCommon.Configure.Using(containerAdapter)
        .ConfigureState<DefaultStateConfiguration>(stateConfig =>
                                                   stateConfig.UseCustomSessionStateOf<HttpSessionState>())
        .ConfigureUnitOfWork<DefaultUnitOfWorkConfiguration>(x =>
                                                             x.AutoCompleteScope())
        .ConfigureData<NHConfiguration>(config => config.WithSessionFactory(() => MarketingDatabaseSessionFactory)
            .WithDistinctResults());



    container.AddComponent("main", typeof(Form1));

    container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("ProductManager.Services").BasedOn(typeof(IService)).WithService.Select((t, baseType) => t.GetInterfaces()));

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(container));

    Form1 mainForm = container.Resolve<Form1>();
    Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

That works great, the DI works for all my services and for my main form. My question is how do I move forward from there? I have the first form working but how do I inject dependencies into the other forms and controls? In MVC there is a way to register all your controllers, I'm looking for something similar with forms, but I'm confused because you have to explicitly instantiate the forms. So, even if I register each form one by one, I don't know how I would shoot off a child form or control without resolving everything myself which misses the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a factory interface for creating windows.  Inject this into forms that need to create and display other forms.

I did something similar with WPF and Windsor in a recent [Visual Studio Magazine article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/10/01/wpf-and-inversion-of-control.aspx) (see the `IViewFactory` implementation). That approach should port to WinForms pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you sir, I looked all over and couldn't find a proper example of this

Comment: I second that! Great article.